# Rename in file error eclipse java

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Hey i have a problem with my android application.I'm trying to download text from given url to Editable box but when i'm running application and hit the button it stops working.
I checked multiple times and it's problem with the jsoup.The device has internet connection.
Here's the code

```
public void sendMessage(View view) throws IOException {
    EditText tf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String kupa = tf.getText().toString();
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(kupa).get();
    String title = doc.text();
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(title);
}
```

cheers guys

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your onCreate():

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Use the above as a temporary solution. Otherwise use thread or asynctask.

Define asynctask like below:

> ```
>  private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask {
>  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) { 
>      EditText tf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
>      String kupa = tf.getText().toString();
>      Document doc = Jsoup.connect(kupa).get();
>      String title = doc.text();
>      return title;
>  }
>
>  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
>      TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
>      tv.setText(result);
>  }  }
> ```

Call the task like below:

```
new DownloadTask().execute();
```